# Stop Matlab from resizing the surface when creating an animated gif

Tags: matlab, animation, image-processing, plot, animated-gif

I'd like to create a 360 degree rotating surface plot using Matlab2013 (Linux 64bit). I can create an animated gif using code snippet beneath but Matlab keeps resizing the surface at some frames throughout the animation (example see [1], frame 56-59). Any idea how I can prevent Matlab from resizing the plot surface?
Thanks in advance for your advice.

```
function createVideo( FigureHandler, filename )
grid on
set(gca,'ZTickLabel',[]);
set(gca,'YTickLabel',[]);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',[]);
for n = 1:360
    view(n,66)
    zoom off
    drawnow
    frame = getframe(FigureHandler);
    im = frame2im(frame);
    [imind,cm] = rgb2ind(im,256);
    if n == 1;
        imwrite(imind,cm,filename,'gif', 'Loopcount',inf);
    else
        imwrite(imind,cm,filename,'gif','WriteMode','append','DelayTime',0);
    end
end
end
```

[1]
http://postimg.org/image/prib1psq5/

Comment: Could you maybe post the code for view(n, 66) or a simplified version of it that shows the resizing? Is it dependent on imwrite or would you also see it on screen without creating the animated gif but just by looking at the matlab figure?

Comment: `view` ships with matlab (it is part of the graph3d toolbox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by the axis limits changing with the view, this could be prevented by manually setting the axis limits or by setting the axis properties `'XLimMode'`,`'YLimMode'` and `'ZLimMode'`, to `'manual'`.

However other properties (e.g. DataAspectRatio, PlotBoxAspectRatio, etc...) will cause the figure to zoom in and out while rotating

Matlab however provides the `vis3d` axis mode to set all of this for you!
All you need to add is:

```
axis('vis3d')
```

which should be place after setting ticks etc... but outside the for loop